# What kind of charts library is being used on this Huffington Post page?

Tags: charts, highcharts, linechart

I like the chart on this huffington post page and I was wondering what kind of charting library is being used? What is the name of the vertical line that appears (in charts jargon) when we hover over the area?

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/donald-trump-iowa_us_56b028a5e4b0b8d7c2306893

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's created with [Highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/)

The vertical line, according to its [documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/tooltip#cross), is "crosshair"